# Use function as JQuery event

Tags: jquery

I am working on the following Click Outside function

```
$(function () {
  jQuery.fn.clickoutside = function (callback) {
    var outside = 1, self = $(this);
    self.cb = callback;
    this.click(function () {
      outside = 0;
    });
    $(document).click(function () {
      outside && self.cb();
      outside = 1;
    });
    return $(this);
  }
});
```

And I am using it has follows:

```
$("nav.menu").clickoutside(function (e) {
  // Do something
});
```

But how can I transform my code to use it as an Event. Something like:

```
$("nav.menu").on("click:outside", function (e) {
  // Do something
});
```

Comment: So, you want to make a custom event?  How would this event be *triggered*?

Comment: Does this help: http://learn.jquery.com/events/introduction-to-custom-events/?

Comment: Basically when the mouse clicks outside of certain elements ...  which is what my function does ...

Comment: outside certain elements, mean click on another element, right?

Comment: It means when I use $("nav.menu, a.link").on("click:outside", function (e) { alert("clicked ouside"); }); the alert will show every time the mouse clicks outside of the elements nav.menu and a.link. My function does exactly that and it works ... But I would like to use this as an event.

Comment: @RocketHazmat I tried to follow that JQuery help to create my event but wasn't able ... That was ahy I asked here ...

Comment: @Miguel: You can't do that.  You can define custom events, but you can only trigger them via `.trigger()`.  The browser doesn't know when to trigger it.

Comment: I got lost ... So it is not possible to create a click:outside custom event?

Comment: Actually... it is possible to create the custom event.  The issue is triggering it.  The browser won't know when to call that event.  You'd have to bind a `.click()` event and then call `.trigger('click:outside')` at the appropriate time.